# Error : "Transport endpoint is already connected"

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, unix-socket

I am trying to develop a small chat server with C.

For a simple chat server,

- ( Transport endpoint ) === ( socket ) ?
- Do i have to use one socket per client, or can I reuse a socket for multiple clients ? If so, how ?
- Is there a standard way of doing this ?
- Any good references available ?

Can i get to see some sample implementations ? I *have to* use gcc compiler and c language for this assignment.

Comment: One question per post, please.  Can you choose just one thing to ask about?  The title of your post has a very good, specific error message, but then your post is not about that at all.

Comment: okey, i would be happy to get the answer for the title.. And yeah, the body led me to the question :)

Comment: If you want us to answer the title question, how about editing all that other stuff out of the body and replacing it with something that helps us answer the title question, such as what code you're trying to run that results in that error?

Comment: @John Zwinick Yup! edited. Need more info ? Anything ?

Answer (score 4):

You need one socket/client and no, you cannot reuse sockets. If you have to handle multiple clients you can:

- create one thread per client and use blocking I/O (preferably with timeout).
- create single threaded program and use demultiplexing with select/poll/epoll/kqueue and use non-blocking I/O.
- use asynchronous I/O.

For C socket communication examples The [Unix Network Programming](http://www.unixnetworkprogramming.com/src.html) book is probably the best source. It has ample of example programs and explanation.

Comment: Sorry to say, i think there is content in what you said but i didn't understand much! I would love to do it in a multi threaded way.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. ( Transport endpoint ) === ( socket ) ?

NO. "Endpoint" means IP address with Port number. Socket presents one "Session" and session consists of two endpoints, local endpoint(IP, port) and remote endpoint(IP, port).

> 1. Do i have to use one socket per client, or can I reuse a socket for
>      multiple clients ? If so, how ?

One socket per one session. That means a server needs to create a new socket for each remote endpoint( client ). You can reuse socket when it's not in use anymore. Look for SO_REUSEADDR socket option.

> 1. Is there a standard way of doing this ?

Not sure what you are asking. A standard way for chat service or for server/client model?
For chat service, look for IRC. Server/Client programming model is well documented. You can Google it.

> 1. Any good references available ?

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Now I believe you understand what the error message means.

Comment: If i want to continuously stream data from 1 client to 1 server (simple strings from stdin) how should i do that ?

Comment: Why don't you read the reference I mentioned? http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html

Comment: I am on it ! going through the reference now.