# Transport endpoint not connected, fails on connect()

Tags: c, sockets, connect, transport

First, I  used `bind()` and `listen()` to bind a port to address 0.0.0.0. However, now I cannot connect.

```
sprintf (addrbuf, "%s-%d", SVR_ADDR, SVR_PORT);
StringToSockaddr (addrbuf, &destAddr);
if (connect(psock,(struct sockaddr *) &destAddr,sizeof(destAddr)) < 0)
    die("failed to connect to server");
printf("connected to server at %s\n",getTime());
```

Comment: What is the error message? Can you post your complete main function such that we have a complete example?

Comment: Is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140438 ?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is implemented correctly?

Comment: Are you sure `psock` is the port and not the socket? Because the first argument to `connect()` should be the client socket, not the port numbert...

Comment: Try getting the error string(perror) after connect failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bind()` function assigns a local address and/or port to the socket.  This is well and good.  The `listen()` function, however, configures the socket as one that will *accept* connections.  If you intend to use the socket to initiate a connection to a remote machine, then you should not use `listen()` on it.

Comment: To "open a new connection" implies using a new socket.  It may or may not be appropriate to first close the original one, but you certainly need to perform a new call to `socket()`, and to `connect()` *that* socket without first configuring it to listen.

Comment: Thank you very much. This clarified the problem!